# A question related to iphone book

Tags: iphone

Can u give me name of books necessary for basic knowledge of making software on iphone with it's indian price?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449101/iphone-development-books (pricing is too localized for this site and is something you can look up on your own)

Answer (score 2):

Head First iPhone Development: A Learner's Guide to Creating Objective-C Applications for the iPhone (Brain-Friendly Guides)

RRP is around 2,352 Indian Rupees (based on converting the UKP RRP of £34.50)

Answer (score 1):

[iPhone SDK Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356255) by Bill Dudney and Chris Adamson.